# ViewWillApear only works once for displaying navigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I'm navigating from a UITableView to a normal ViewController.

I'm displaying the navigationBar like this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}
```

The first time I hit a row in the UITableView, the navigationBar shows up, but the second time it remains hidden. This is not expected behavior, since viewWillAppear should work every time the view shows up.

Why is the navigationBar hidden when viewing the view for the second time?

Comment: By default, navigation controllers show their nav bars. When are you hiding the nav bar in your code and how?

Comment: I'm hiding my code int he UITableViewController. I do so by this code: `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}` sorry for the inconsistency

Comment: So, I'm guessing the first UITableVC is the root VC of a NavigationController and you're using a push segue to the regular VC? But, you're hiding the navbar in the TableVC and showing it in the regular VC?

Comment: it's not the root, actually. It's one of the views of a tab bar controller. If you tab a certain tab, you are segued to the uitableview. If you tab a cell on this tableview, you will be segued to also a view of the tab bar controller, only some data is transferred along with it. The two views are siblings.

Comment: Are you using push segues throughout?

Comment: I use it on different views in my app as well, but not related to the tab bar controller.

Comment: Did you check the viewWillAppear invoked every time?

Comment: @trick14 I'm not sure what you mean, but the above method is my entire viewWillAppear method in that VC

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: Each of the controllers in the tabs should be embedded in its own navigation controller (if they need one), so whether one of them shows its navigation bar or not shouldn't affect how another one shows its.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are hiding navigation bar in `viewWillAppear` of table view. So it will hidden for other pushed view controllers. So in order to get rid of that you have to un hide navigation bar in view did disappear of table view.So it will work in desired manner.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
}
```